# Update Recycler view by button in toolbar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I writing app for Android using Xamarin.

I have this code in Activity for OnCreate method.

```
    protected override int LayoutResource
    {
        get { return Resource.Layout.Main; }
    }

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar activityIndicator;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);


        recyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
        activityIndicator = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.activityIndicator);

        activityIndicator.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.Vertical, false);

        recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        var repository = new TestAppRepository();

        var films = await repository.GetAllFilms();

        var formsAdapter = new FormAdapter(films.results);

        recyclerView.SetAdapter(formsAdapter);

        activityIndicator.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;

        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

I have Button in toolbar and need to refresh Recycler when I tap this button.

Here is calling of it for display

```
 public override  bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.home, menu);
        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

How I need to write code to refresh Recycler?

Thank's for help

Comment: Try to notify adapter like recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); on tap click.

Answer (score 0):

Use the button's `setOnClickListener` method and implement the `onClick` method of the `new OnClickListener` In the `onClick` method called the RecyclerView adapter's `notifydatasetchanged()`

Comment: `public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {


            //Toast.MakeText(this, "Top ActionBar pressed: " + item.TitleFormatted, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }`

I set listener like this, how I need to refresh Recycler now?

Comment: In the `OnOptionsItemSelected()` write the following - `formsAdapter.notifydatasetchanged()`

Comment: I need to write it in brackets? Or in method?

Comment: `public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item) { //Toast.MakeText(this, "Top ActionBar pressed: " + item.TitleFormatted, ToastLength.Short).Show(); formsAdapter.notifydatasetchanged(); return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item); }` Use this

Comment: but `formsAdapter` is in OnCreate and it isn't visible

Comment: make the formsAdapter as a global variable